# ZipArchive download failed

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'am using *ZipArchive* class to generate and download zipFile. It must be work on php **5.2.14**.
It works perfectly on **php 5.3.x** with this code:

```
$filename = "test.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$opened = $zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);

$zip->addFromString(...,...);
$zip->close();

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile("$filename");
exit();
```

On **php 5.2.14** it produces an empty (0 byte size) zip file. If I remove the *exit()* instruction it produces a corrupted zip file.

Solutions?

Comment: Add Content-length header describing size of zip file in bytes.

Comment: And also check that there is absolutely no white space before opening <? and after closing ?>

Answer (score -1):

i'm posting a portion of my program which use the ZipArchive Class

```
$this->licensePlate = "AA000AA";
$this->fileName = "path/to/file/tmp.zip";
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Foto_'.$this->licensePlate.'.zip"');
readfile($this->fileName);
```

Are you sure you're actually adding the files to the ZipArchive? 
Are you sure you're actually have the permission to create the ZipArchive?